# Log4j2 WildFly 9 log file empty

Tags: logging, log4j2, wildfly-10

I'm working on Wildfly 9/10.
I wrote my web application with my custom Log4j2 configuration file.

```
<configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="General" fileName="D:/logs/general/general.log"
        filePattern="D:/logs/general/$${date:yyyy-MM}/general-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout
            pattern="%d{ABSOLUTE} %level{length=5} [%thread] %logger{1} - %msg%n" />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB" />
    </RollingFile>
    <Async name="asyncGeneral" bufferSize="10" includeLocation="true">
        <AppenderRef ref="General" />
    </Async>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO">         
        <AppenderRef ref="asyncGeneral" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

The configuration file is correctly included inside a war jar lib.

The result is that when i run the web application it generates the file:

```
D:/logs/general.log
```

But it continues to print the log on the server console, while the file keeps to remain empty.

The same configuration works properly on a standalone application.
What am i missing?

UPDATE
when i deploy my application the server prints this debug level informations:

```
12:58:17,190 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) 2016-06-16 12:58:17,190 ServerService Thread Pool -- 64 DEBUG createAppender(={General}, errorRef="null", blocking="true", shutdownTimeout="0", bufferSize="10", name="asyncGeneral", includeLocation="true", Filter=null, Configuration(vfs:/C:/Windows/System32/content/sec-api.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.application.jar/log4j2.xml), ignoreExceptions="true")

12:58:17,194 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) 2016-06-16 12:58:17,194 ServerService Thread Pool -- 64 DEBUG createAppenders(={Console, RoutingAppender, General,asyncGeneral})

12:58:17,196 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) 2016-06-16 12:58:17,196 ServerService Thread Pool -- 64 DEBUG  reateAppenderRef(ref="asyncGeneral", level="null", Filter=null)

12:58:17,200 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) 2016-06-16 12:58:17,200 ServerService Thread Pool -- 64 DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="DEBUG", includeLocation="null", ={async, asyncGeneral, asyncDebug}, ={}, Configuration(vfs:/C:/Windows/System32/content/sec-api.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.klopotek.core-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/log4j2.xml), Filter=null)

12:58:17,225 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) 2016-06-16 12:58:17,224 ServerService Thread Pool -- 64 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=/sec-api,component=AsyncAppenders,name=asyncGeneral
```

Comment: Please change the status from INFO to DEBUG. I would then recommend creating a Jira issue and attaching your configuration file and log to the Jira issue. If possible, providing a sample project that could be run to reproduce the problem would be even better.

Comment: do you mean it s simply a bug? i read in some post that perheps it s necessary to exclude the wildfly standard logging

Comment: I can't say whether it is a bug or not with the information above. You may need to configure willdfly. If you do, I would like to get that documented on the Log4j site.

Comment: ok... i added more information above... the point is that it seems that wildfly keeps to use it logging system ignoring log4j2 configured by me.

Comment: The `[stdout]` means that log4j2 is logging to `System.out`. Double check that you don't have multiple configuration files in your deployment. Also what are you expecting to see in the file? Anything logged by the server, e.g. Hibernate logs, will not be able to log into that file.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration shows only a RollingFile and Async Appender. Yet, the log clearly shows a Console and Routing appender. I am seeing references to two different configuration files so it appears you may be using a CompositeConfiguration? In any case, the configuration you are showing doesn't align with the log messages so it is difficult to say what the issue is.